# signal for windows and linux IPC

Tags: linux, windows, concurrency, signals, ipc

In order for code compatible among Windows and Linux/Unix.  I want to use MingW’s tool sets and CodeBlocks for development so the code can be compiled and run on both Linux and Windows.  The system I try to design is a very busy, heavy data exchange system like server and clients, all running in the same box, and timing is critical.  So I need IPC among Server and Client.  I want to use user signals to inform many clients to conduct some data processing actions at some specific times.  That means I need a set of signals for different actions.  When I send those signals to the clients, I also need to send one or two parameters with it.  Those IPC methods such as event handling, messaging, slots, named pipe, sockets may not work for my purpose because they need the client to pump/peek the incoming information constantly, which will cost CPU for a busy system.)  So the idea method will be the signal and clients are sleeping and will only wake up to do the jobs once it receives the signals.
For Linux side, looks like I can have enough user signals to use (sigaction for specific) .  But for Windows side the signals are limited to SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, SIGTERM.  No user signals and cannot pass parameters.   Also, I need the server to be able to broadcast signals to all clients by their pid.  I looked at boost and others, so far could not find one I can use for Windows.
Any suggestion?

Comment: How about taking any **actor-model** for this goal, where all of the above said requirements are granted by-design, right in the grounds of the already mature eco-systems, instead of trying to build literally heaps of design-side compromises on how to bypass / circumvent each and all of O/S-related constraints just to finally ( hopefully ) arrive to something more or less similar to what the native actor-based ecosystems already have from a Day 0 up and running, ready for efficient re-use in user-defined applications?

Comment: Use sockets. They are perfectly fine for these use-cases, are sane to handle compare compared to signals, and will have the same wakeup behavior you expect from signals - an application blocked on `read()` will only be woken up once there is data available.

Comment: sockets are too slow here.  Assume it is via tcp/ip, even used in local.

Comment: I decided using boost's messaging queue to do the job since signal trapping is very hard to handle the status and passing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using boost's messaging queue and shared memory.  messaging acts as signal and shared memory for passing large data.  Will test other method later for CPU performance comparing.